# How to start literate programming?

Tags: discussion

I remember having read somewhere that the meta section is for the questions that are not directly related to TeX but can't find it back. However, I hope this is the right place for my question.

Knuth is famous for his Literate Programming and since I've read about it, I've made a habit of writing the how and why in my comments (which now represent about 60-70% of my code). I'd like to give a try to Literate Programming but all I can find about it on google describes the ideology, not how to do it. Does anyone know where to start?

Comment: Probably TeX: The Program (Reading, Massachusetts: Addison-Wesley, 1986), xviii+600pp.
ISBN 0-201-13437-3 will be a good starting point to find how it may be done.

Comment: Literate programming is 'like writing an essay rather than a program'.  Write an essay about your program—defend it *as* you present it.  Start from a problem description and then tackle each part of the problem using your words and then some high-level code, eventually getting down to the nitty-gritty.  Usually makes for an anti-climactic ending, but it gets the job done.

Comment: @SeanAllred the problem is: when that part is done, how do I get the program out of the essay/how do I compile my program to get a nice documentation? It's quite frustrating if I have to first write my program and after rewrite it in a well-formatted document that explains it...

Comment: Ahhhh. In TeX terms, you're talking about how to use `web` — I recommend `noweb` if you're doing general language stuff, but the 'official' one is `cweb` for C-like languages (C, C++, Java).  (I think plain `web` is just Pascal, but I'm not sure.)  However, I'd really recommend using `org-babel` for this, if you're ready to take the plunge into the (seriously) wonderful world of emacs. `:-)`

Comment: @SeanAllred Sorry but I already plunged into the (even) wonderful world of vim ;-). Thanks for pointing out `*web`, that's what I was looking for. I'll have a look at `noweb`

Comment: `<insert enflaming stab at eVil here>` ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure Meta is the place for it, since Meta is 'questions about questions'/'questions about the site', but it can be moved if necessary.

Depending on the programming language you're using, you're going to want to take a look at either WEB (original by Knuth, supporting TeX over Pascal), [CWEB](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/cweb.html) (Silvio Levy with Knuth, supporting C, C++, and Java), or [one of the various other tools available](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming#Tools).  (I personally recommend [`noweb`](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/noweb/) in conjunction with [`org-babel`](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html)—the combination is very easy to work with, and `org` supports documentation export to many different formats.  LyX also apparently works with `noweb`, but I haven't tried it.)

I can only give advice on how to use `org-babel`, but the workflow for standalone `web` derivatives seems to be the same:

1. Acquire a version of `web` that you'd like to use, making sure to go through a `Hello, World` example.
2. Write literate program—comments and code all in one(?) file.
3. Use `tangle` to extract source code and `weave` to extract documentation.  I imagine this is done using

   ```
   ctangle literate-program.web
   cweave literate-program.web
   ```

   or the syntax your tool uses.  (This can almost always be gotten with `mytool --help`.)

Comment: I didn't really understand the question, but seeing your answer, I think that the question could be either on [our main TeX.SX site](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) or [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) ;)

Comment: If your language is R then `knitr` is your tool.

Comment: Programmers.SE seems to be the better fit—this isn't TeX-specific or TeX-central.  TeX is merely an output format here.